# Get env variables from .env or dockerFile/docker-compose.yml, to config,php to connect to mysql database

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

Instead of hardcoding the db_username and password, I want to define a env variable in docker. I am new to Docker, so some stuff I still need to learn more about.

Another question i want to ask is, if someone else want to run my container, like clone from github, they will have to set themselves the env variables to connect to db right? Create a .env and stuff like that..

config.php

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', getenv('DB_SERVER'));
define('DB_USERNAME', getenv('DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASSWORD', getenv('DB_PASSWORD')); 
define('DB_NAME', getenv('DB_NAME'));

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if ($link === false) {
    die ("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

.env

```
DB_SERVER=db
DB_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=dbpassword
DB_NAME=company
```

docker-compose.yml

```
db:
  build: ./backend
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dbpassword
php:
  build: ./frontend
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes: 
    - ./frontend:/var/www/html
  environment:
    - DB_SERVER=${DB_SERVER}
    - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}
    - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
  env_file: ./.env
  links:
    - db
```

Dockerfile in ./frontend

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY . /var/www/html/
```

Dockerfile in ./backend

```
FROM mysql:5.7

COPY ./demo.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

I don't know if the way it is right now, is getting the variables form the env file, when i run with the docker-compose up, and go to 192.168.99.100, my application is working, but i get

In the .yml file, i think i don't need the environment variables set, but i was testing if i could get that variables, directly put into the config.php, for someone who will run my container, only need to run "docker-compose up" and not set everything.

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'dbuser'@'172.17.0.3' (using password: YES) in
>   /var/www/html/config.php on line 8

I don't know how to solve that. So basically, it's two questions, why this error, and if I'm doing the environment variables right.

Comment: PHP seems to get the environment variables as it's trying to access the database with `dbuser`. I assume the mysql docker is using the root user though as you set your password as the root password. So I think you either need to define your custom user to the mysql container, or you need to change php to use the root user

Comment: @JimL You're right, it's getting the variables, i will try to do both of these things, thanks!

Comment: @JimL Trying to set php to use root user gave me this error: 
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host '172.17.0.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /var/www/html/config.php on line 8

Comment: I suggest you try to set it up with the ENVs for database, user and password so you don't use the root user. It's usually locked down anyway. https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ Do note that if you use a volume for persisting the db then the user/db setup will only run when that volume is created. So changes you do now to the mysql container might not be seen until you wipe the volume

Comment: I managed to get it to work, i don't really know what i changed, but basically i removed the `environment:` from the php container,
and moved to the db container, using the mysql image env variables from the dockerhub. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem
You need to add variable PHP_FPM_CLEAR_ENV=no

> ```
> environment:
>   - PHP_FPM_CLEAR_ENV=no
> ```

After that everything is ok!

Comment: I needed just one variable and I used this one: `environment: - MY_VAR=$MY_VAR` and then using `getenv('MY_VAR')` it works

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work, i don't really know what i changed, but basically i removed the `environment:` from the `php` container, and moved to the `db` container, using the mysql image env variables from the dockerhub.