# PHP container connect to external DB

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to connect my project php with an external MYSQL database.

Currently, i use this docker-compose wtih Dockerfile :

**Dockefile**

```
FROM php:5.6-apache-jessie

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-file
RUN apt-file update
RUN apt-get install -y vim bash net-tools
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
```

EDIT docker-compose :

```
  version: '3.8'

services:
    db:
        image: mariadb:10.1
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        restart: always
        environment:
                - MYSQL_HOST=IP_EXTERNAL_DB
                - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=AMAZING_PASSWORD
                - MYSQL_DATABASE=NAME_OF_DATABASE_TRY_TO_CONNECT
                - MYSQL_USER=USER
                - MYSQL_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        environment: 
            - PHP_FPM_CLEAR_ENV=no
        links:
            - db
```

PHP is ok, but the connection to external DB doesn't work.

I know i'm missing something, but i can't find it.

Any ideas ? :)

Comment: You could check out  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969282/get-env-variables-from-env-or-dockerfile-docker-compose-yml-to-config-php-to-c) related question first

Comment: Thanks @Benni.

I looked at the topic, I added in docker-compose with a MYSQL container with db variables (mariadb: 10.1).

I am using the script from the topic to connect to DB.

But I have an error:

Warning: mysqli_connect (): (HY000 / 1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.210.3'

This ip is not the ip I added as a variable.

Sorry I really have a hard time understanding.

Comment: Access denied means that the authentication failed. That means there is an invalid username or password combination

Comment: For SQL, it's obvious that the user can be root. So please go to your phpMyAdmin and check from the user's tab. You may find out the password set on the root account

Comment: I took over an old project, and in it there was already a config file with envs for the DB.

Hell.

Thank you both for your help!